# Accessing data on another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a winform and some threads. When i try to access a field in the winform from one of the threads, the following error occurs :
 `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

How can i resolve this problem?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multithreading help, yet again (winForms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999020/multithreading-help-yet-again-winforms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All controls have a method called Invoke, which takes a delegate as the first argument and optional *params object[]*.
You can use this method easily:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(DoSomething));
```

where

```
void DoSomething()
{
    richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
}
```

The delegate MethodInvoker is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace, which, I suppose, you are already using.

You can even invoke from the same thread!

You can also use parameters, like this:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new ColorChanger(DoSomething), Color.Cyan);
```

where

```
delegate void ColorChanger(Color c);

void DoSomething(Color c)
{
    richTextBox1.BackColor = c;
}
```

I hope this helped!

Edit:
`InvokeRequired` is required if you are using the same method from a... basically... unknown thread.
So it would look like this:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(DoSomething));
    else
    {
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
        // Here should go everything the method will do.
    }
}
```

You may call this method from ANY thread!

And for parameters:

```
delegate void ColorChanger(Color c);

void DoSomething(Color c)
{
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new ColorChanger(DoSomething), c);
    else
    {
        richTextBox1.BackColor = c;
        // Here should go everything the method will do.
    }
}
```

Enjoy programming!

Comment: Multumesc mult Vercas! :D Very detailed ! +1

Comment: oh and another question! why are these invokes required? i mean, what is the purpose of using this kind of invokes? Why can't i just call directly ?

Answer (score 2):

In your Thread code, before changing textBox1, check `textBox1.InvokeRequired` and if so, use `textBox1.Invoke(aDelegate)`

Comment: I'll look for some links, this Q is a dupe.

Comment: so i've used the following code : 'public void setText(String a)
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(setText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { a });
            }
            else
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text = a;
            }'
         

        }'

Comment: my question is, what does this code actually mean? what does it do?

Comment: @Badescu, "what does this code actually mean?" It means that when you're on another thread (InvokeRequired==true) then you have to Invoke your action to the MessageLoop. It will be executed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

what Vercas suggested works fine, but if you love inline code you may also try to choose an anonymous delegate

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
    delegate() {
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    ));
```

+1 to him :)

Answer (score 1):

Salut Alexandru

You may want to check out an alternative way, the

> BackgroundWorker

component. It is really easy and confortable to use. More details and samples you can find here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

This component is also very important one in .NET and very usefull to know.

Comment: multumesc! I'll look into it!

Comment: Even if he used a background worker, he'd still need to use that way to update controls.